# Area 51 unknown committer role shows HTML tags as plain text

Tags: bug, status-completed, area-51

The "unknown" committer role shows as "`<em>unknown</em>`" in the listing on the right side, for example on the [LEGO proposal](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/10919/lego).

[image: Screenshot]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This double-encoding bug was introduced when converting the view to Razor last Friday.

It's fixed now. Thanks.